# Debugger with conditional breakpoints

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, trace

There is a program (not mine) that running on the operating system windows. I want to debug this program and stop when will comply with certain conditions, sum eax + ebx register will be equal to 65463. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know of any Windows debugger, that supports globally monitoring register contents. As far as I know, you can only set conditions, that are evaluated at specific, pre-set code locations.

Comment: I am sure if the debugger can trace the code, it can control every step. I think that this will be a very useful tool.

Comment: A debugger doesn't trace code. It sets up traps at the locations selected by the user, either by using dedicated CPU facilities, or by temporarily writing `int3` instructions.

Comment: @IInspectable but they can single step, and some are scriptable. `gdb` can certainly do this, but not very fast :)

Comment: @Jester: That's true. A creative single-step script might get you there. WinDbg will do just fine. Although running code like that is surely going to expose lots of bugs that would otherwise not show up. Plus, you'd also have to make sure that your script attaches to all threads that are launched along the way. Worth a try anyway, if that's all you have at your disposal.